# Warnings on Spanish text processing Stanford CoreNLP Number in types > column for ... is probably priority

Tags: stanford-nlp

I've downloaded the Stanford CoreNLP from https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html current version 3.9.2

Downloaded the Spanish Language JAR

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-spanish-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.jar

Put that in application root folder.

Fired up server with:

> C:\Stanford>java -mx4g -cp "*"
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer - port 9000 -timeout
>   15000

Loaded http://localhost:9000

Entered the text "Sí, sabes que ya llevo un rato mirándote" and selected "Spanish" and Submit.

In the console readout there are lots of warning like:

> [pool-1-thread-1] WARN
>   edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexNERAnnotator - Number in types
>   column for [ejecución] is probably priority: 1

Output suggests defaults are working OK, but what misconfiguration is causing this warning?

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be resolved in future versions.  The output doesn't mean anything regarding performance, it's just that the rules files for Spanish were missing a column.  We've fixed the files, so in 4.0.0 and on those warnings should go away.